# How to tell IE a HTML file on shared location is not a security risk?

Tags: javascript, html, security, internet-explorer, activex

to rename I'm using using ActiveX, in JavaScript. But that HTML is shared location that can be accessible with in the group.

Since it is a shared file, I cannot add it to trusted sites (IE expects a domain here).

I do not want to change security settings for the default zone.

Any idea how to permanently unblock it? browser support is IE8 and above.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would it help to use ssl?

Comment: How to configure ssl for shared drive, even if configure that is not possible. Customer is not happy with this approach.